# Using Swiftmailer in Symfony 4 (prod mode)

Tags: swiftmailer, symfony4

I'm trying to configure the MAILER_URL var in my domain.com.conf file in a VPS using vestacp panel.

I got it in dev mode for a gmail account in .env file:

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://descubriendoargentina.com:*******@localhost
```

It works fine, but in prod mode I have not got it yet. I have this in the apache2 conf file:

```
SetEnv MAILER_URL "gmail://descubriendoargentina.com:*******@localhost"
```

I tried too in the same file using my server smtp conf:

```
SetEnv MAILER_URL "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=null&auth_mode=login&username=descubriendoargentina&password=*****"
```

I have those lines in config/package/swiftmailer.yaml:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

The mail accounts (both) fine good.

On the other hand I need export the export APP_ENV=prod in console to work in prod mode. I've read in stackoverflow.com all about this problem but nothing I read works for me.